# How can I put all dependencies into one folder inside a JAR file with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, minecraft

I'm using Maven and several libraries in my project, some of them are nested in the final JAR file.

**The file structure inside the JAR file now looks like this:**

```
jar
│
├───com
│   ├───feniksovich (my project)
│   └───zaxxer (hikari shaded lib directory)                 
│
├───org
│   ├───apache (commons-io shaded lib directory)
│   └───slf4j (slf4j shaded lib directory)
└───redis (jedis shaded lib directory)
```

**Is it possible to make it look something like this?**

```
jar
│
├───com
│   └───feniksovich (my project)               
│
└───libs
    ├───com
    │   └───zaxxer (hikari shaded lib directory)
    ├───org
    │   ├───apache (commons-io shaded lib directory)
    │   └───slf4j (slf4j shaded lib directory)
    └───redis (jedis shaded lib directory)
```

My current `pom.xml`: https://paste.lucko.me/fgMSBhCtpM

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you should write that you are already using maven-shade-plugin which is the result the maven-shade-plugin produces (so called executable jar)... furthermore why do you like/need the requested structure? Which problem do you exactly have?

Comment: It is possible but the system classloader will not understand it unless you also rewrite the byte code to conform to the new package babes.  This is non trivial.

Comment: @khmarbaise
I really don't have any problems and would just like to structure the contents of the JAR  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen
Got it. It is not worth it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The structure of the JAR needs to follow the names of the packages.